# Add React app to static HTML page from another folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react app with multiple components as part of something bigger and I want to display that react app in a HTML page. I saw other posts but they had everything in a script file with the component in the script tag itself. I have a fully functioning chat app in another folder and I wanted to render that in the HTML file.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="html_container">

    </div>


    <script src="./reactApp/src/App.js">
        <!-- add some magic here to have the app from the folder show up here -->
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App />,
            document.getElementById('html_container')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an iframe to render the react app inside the page, with the `src` linking to your react app.

Comment: That gets the code from App.js. Is there a way to run it? I open the app by doing `npm start`

Comment: In this case I am assuming the React App is already running and hosted elsewhere. If possible, it would probably be easier to move the React app to another project, separate of the current one that you're trying to make

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, but what I was originally doing was putting the path to the App.js file instead of putting the http link in the src. I didn't realize this earlier lol. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. Sounds good. I'm glad you have it working now!